# How can I get SQL 2012 Web Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, licensing

If I want to get a copy of SQL 2012 Web Edition, do I have to go through a hosting provider such as Rackspace? What about if I am in the MS Select program and a Volume Licensing account?

How is it licensed? Is it also a per core license?

Also, can I restore a database from an SQL 2012 Development Edition instance to an SQL 2012 Web Edition instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I want to get a copy of SQL 2012 Web Edition, do I have to go through a hosting provider 
>   such as Rackspace

No, you can also sign a SPLA agreement yourself.

> Is it also a per core license?

Prety much. Per processor.

> can I restore a database from an SQL 2012 Development Edition instance to an SQL 2012 Web 
>   Edition instance?

Maybe, maybe not. As in - depends. As in: Developer is Enterprise, technically - you can also not restore it on a STANDARD if you use enterprise features. Same with Web. Backup/Restore is not a good way to manage that anyway, deployment scripts are, especially later when you go on developping new features.